# boot loader installed on usb pendrive

Tags: bootloader

I desktop with pre-installed Win 7 
I have  install 12.04 along side Windows on different partitions of my disk with my usb pendrive.

Ubuntu installed successfully and working fine,and win 7 also working fine. but when i am booting the system where boot menu not appearing, automatically login to win 7.

when i am trying to boot with usb pen drive it showing boot menu (grub), 
in the boot menu if i am selecting Ubuntu it login to Ubuntu normally.
without pendrive it is not login to ubuntu.

how to solve this problem. without reinstalling the os.

please help me for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "grub" bootloader to your harddrive, not to your USB pen drive.

---

After this step, you will be able to choose which operating system to boot, you won't need the usb stick anymore to use ubuntu.

**Step 1:**
Identify your hard disk device entry -> one of /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc.
Usually, it is /dev/sda. 
If you are not sure, check at the command line (Terminal):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In the output, first line is important as you'll recognize the size of your hard disk. 
If you have the usb stick too, you will have /dev/sda with any partitions like /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, etc **AND** /dev/sdb -> your usb stick:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e26f3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    40962047    20480000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048   275718143   117378048    5  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107861504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773167 sectors
         ......and other stuff ..........
```

**Step 2:**
Install grub

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score -2):

Holà! I believe -if I'm understood well- the pendrive has only a link to Boot/vmlinuz and
if present, the pendrive does the exact link  or nothing if it's absent…
Seems to me, the link could be copyied on hard disk.
Courage!

Comment: No, this won't work. The bootloader needs to be installed on the hard drive, e.g. `grub-install ...`